# Only get 5 items

Tags: jquery

I got this AJAX call to a XML file, WOrks fine.
But i only want to have item 2-6,and not them all.
How can i do that?

```
$(xml).find('item').each(function(){

            var toplist_no = $(this).find('no').text();
            var toplist_user = $(this).find('user').text();
            var toplist_won = $(this).find('won').text();
            var toplist_loose = $(this).find('loose').text();

            $('#toplisttable_' + cno + ' tr:last').after('<tr><td>' + toplist_no + '(' + cno + ')</td><td>' + toplist_user + '</td><td>' + toplist_won + '-' + toplist_loose + '</td></tr>');

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might just add a counter?

```
var counter = 0; 
$(xml).find('item').each(function(){

    // skip first item
    // or items beyond the fifth

    if (counter == 0) {
        counter++; // increase counter
        continue; // skip everything after this statement
    }

    if (counter > 4) {
        // larger then 4
        // we can stop the loop here
        break;
    }

    var toplist_no = $(this).find('no').text();
    var toplist_user = $(this).find('user').text();
    var toplist_won = $(this).find('won').text();
    var toplist_loose = $(this).find('loose').text();

    $('#toplisttable_' + cno + ' tr:last').after('<tr><td>' + toplist_no + '(' + cno + ')</td><td>' + toplist_user + '</td><td>' + toplist_won + '-' + toplist_loose + '</td></tr>');

    counter++;

});
```

Answer (score 3):

Try slice:

```
$(xml).find('item').slice(2,6).each(...
```

http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/slice

Answer (score 1):

you can count the iterations like :

```
 k = 0; 

 $(xml).find('item').each(function(){
    if(k <= 5){
      ...do your stuff
    }else {
      return false;//breaks the loop
    }
    k++;
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Insert `.filter(function(i){return (i>=2)&&(i<=6)})` before your `.each`

http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/traversing_filter.asp

Answer (score 0):

note: you don't have to define extra variable, the callback function in each() takes index as parameter `.each(function(i){...})`